# HTML sessionStorage scope and life span

Tags: javascript, html, session-storage

I have read that:

> The session storage uses the sessionStorage object to store data on a
>   temporary basis, for a single window (or tab). The data disappears
>   when session ends i.e. when the user closes that window (or tab)

I have 2 html files stored locally. I populate a session Storage item when File1 is loaded. Without closing the tab I try to open File2 (using browser address bar). It seems I cannot retrieve the same session Storage item now.

Is this supposed to work like this? When I move back to the File1 html page, I can still see the value.

Why does this happen?

Comment: is the same domain¿?

Comment: Locally as in `file:///…`? I’m surprised that that even works within a single filename. Different local files have to be isolated, anyway.

Comment: There's no recommended to have sessions across tabs. Look [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/106435/why-does-owasp-recommend-disable-web-browser-cross-tab-sessions)

Comment: use a static web server such as 'http-server' of nodejs to serve static files. Don't use file://

Answer (score 1):

If you are using, chrome browser you can open developer to check weather your session storage has saved (also available on other browser) , and also can check weather have share among the tab.

[image]

As my experience, session storage is able to share among the tab, but not recommenced, data may lose once browser crash.